# Complex integration around the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Integrate along the unit circle : ∫e^(x-iy)dz. I am not able to apply Residue Theorem. Substitution of z=e^it makes integration very complicated. How should I evaluate the given integral. Please help.

Comment: Note that $x-iy=\bar z=\frac{1}{z}$ on the unit circle, so use the Taylor series of the exponential expressed in $\frac{1}{z}$ and integrate term by term as only one integral of all is non-zero

Comment: @Conrad How do we justify term by term integration of the infinite Taylor series?

Comment: absolute convergence on compact sets (avoiding zero here as the terms are in $\frac{1}{z}$ but the unit circle definitely qualifies!)